# How can I call a stored procedure from another stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have two store procedures, in one of them I want to get one field form my view that has a Date value.

In the another one which is called `StoredProcedure` I want to convert the output value of first stored procedure to Hijri Shamsi Date:

This is my first stored procedure that gets the date column:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetExamDate 
    @Id INT
AS
    SELECT ExamTime 
    FROM View_SubjectStudyCourse
    WHERE @Id = CourseId
GO
```

and then I want to use the below code in the second procedure to converts the Gregorian date to Hijri date is:

```
DECLARE @DateTime AS DATETIME
SET @DateTime = GETDATE()

SELECT 
    @DateTime AS [Gregorian Date],
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), @DateTime, 131) AS [Gregorian date to Hijri date]
GO
```

Now I don't know how to use the above code in second stored procedure and how can I return value of the `GetExamDate Procedure` in the second procedure?!

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In First Stored Procedure, return the date as an out parameter

In Second Stored Procedure,

```
DECLARE @examDate DateTime
EXECUTE GetExamDate @examDate OUTPUT
```

Then you can use the value of @examDate, which is the result from 1st SP.

Comment: @dorsa: hope this helped. If so please mark it an an answer so that it helps anyone who refers to it later.

Comment: Thx Habeeb, I do that.but how can I call the 1st SP in the second SP?!

Comment: @dorsa, the above example is the way you call the 1st SP in the 2nd SP.